# Swagger Code-Gen - Inheritance

Tags: inheritance, swagger, springfox, swagger-codegen

Should swagger code gen for java objects handle inheritance?

I have annotated my objects with subTypes and discriminator in the ApiModel annotation and then ran swagger code gen and I get all of the classes now but there is no inheritance maintained between them.

Does anyone have ane example of this working?

Comment: Could you add what you've tried to your answer (code)?

Comment: Hey sorry I forgot about this post, I have had a reply from some of the spring fox guys and it seems it is spring fox that doesnt support the inheritance currently. There is a PR containing the fix but it needs to be reworked and wont make it into the next release, it might go in April 2017.

Comment: @berimbolo Did you find any workaround for this issue. I am also using inheritence and want swagger to reflect the same. Please, share your workaround for the same

Comment: Sorry I didnt, in the end we decided to do away with swagger and have removed it as it wasn't fit for our purposes. Last time I checked they still had not actually written the functionality into the library.